# Ruby: Map a function over something if array, do it once if a single object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently doing this for one of my functions in Ruby:

```
if @to_pass.kind_of?(Array)
        @to_pass.map do {|item| do_a_function(item)}
    else
        do_a_function(item)
    end
```

Is there a shorter way of doing "if this is an array, map over and apply the function, if not, then do the function"?

Comment: do you mean `do_a_function(@to_pass)` in the else branch?

Comment: @platzhirsch for now it's either an object of type x of an array made of those objects.

Comment: Instead of looking for a shorter way of doing it, I would rather make it so that it's not necessary. Where does this value come from? Could you modify the code that produces it so that it's always an array?

Comment: @hdgarrood It's a pageant management app that I'm making in Sinatra, basically scores are sent either individually or by bulk via another web app. So I can't be sure if it's an array or an object. I'm still learning this part so feel free to tell me if what I'm doing is wrong.

Comment: Ahh, ok. If there's only one of these "if array, then map, else call directly" blocks, then probably not worth worrying about. One suggestion: you might be able to define a class representing the data that your web app's received, and do all of this testing whether there are lots of scores or just one in its `initialize`, so that no other part of your app knows about this "is it an object or a collection" issue?

Comment: But, on second thoughts, it might also be a good idea to ignore me. I've only seen 5 lines of your app; I can't really comment on how (or even, if) it should be refactored.

Comment: I think I get what you mean. Basically the parts that are duplicated, I put in a function so I can test that function's functionality by itself. I'm going to refactor it later, still learning this thing

Answer (score 3):

You can just convert a single object into an array. If you are not using the output, each would be better than map as it would not create a new array.

```
# if single object doesn't respond to to_a
# as Guilherme Bernal pointed out in comments, flatten(1) should be used rather than flatten
[@to_pass].flatten(1).each {|item| do_a_function(item) }

# if it does
@to_pass.to_a.each {|item| do_a_function(item) }
```

Comment: Should use `flatten(1)` instead of `flatten` so that it will work when `@to_pass` is a array of arrays.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Thanks, I never knew flatten also receives an argumant

Comment: Any idea why `each` wasn't designed to take a symbol as `inject` does and just apply it to each element?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin You can always convert a symbol to a proc: `class Fixnum; def print; p self; end; end; [1,2,3].each(&:print)`

Comment: @rubish, also `to_a` may not work as expected if `@to_pass` is a Hash.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal I'm trying to understand why the answer doesn't recommend something like `each(&:do_a_function)`

Comment: @PeterAlfvin, because it will call the method on the object, like this `obj.do_something`, not like `do_something(obj)`.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal As I understood anybody looking at the code would try it before assuming it is working correctly and hashes wouldn't.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `Array` method, which will either create an array containing the single item or just return the original array.

```
Array(@to_pass).map { |item| do_a_function(item) }
```

Comment: Not sure if this works, I tested something like this: Array({id: 1, hello: 4}).map {|item| puts item} and what happens is that the output is 

id
1
hello
4

as opposed to {id: 1, hello: 4}.

Comment: @DaryllSantos Correct. The `Array` method converts hashes to an array of key-value pairs.

Comment: Good catch - you are probably better of requiring that any arguments to your method conform to a common interface. In this case you want whatever is passed in to conform to `map` anything else (like a simple object) will just crash and burn. Other than that your initial implementation will do the job but is pretty ugly because you are trying to add extra `flexibility`

Comment: Yes, right now since this is a REST service in Sinatra I have to structure and refactor the app carefully and that the implementation is sort of clunky, any tips on designing REST services?

Answer (score 1):

You could transform always to array and make use of flatten, like this:

```
([@to_pass].flatten).map { |item| do_a_function(item) }
```

This works because `flatten` will keep already flattened arrays as they are.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this:

```
[*@to_pass].map{ |e|
  ...
}
```

If `@to_pass` is a single element or an array it will be converted to an array.

Comment: This is like the Array method: I tested this: [*{id: 1, hello: 4}].map {|item| puts item} and what happens is that the output is id 1 hello 4 as opposed to {id: 1, hello: 4}.

Comment: You are passing a hash, not an array like your question stated. Are you changing the question? If you pass a hash `[*hash].map` will pass each key/value pair. That's just like `hash.map` would do.

Comment: Um the {id:1, hello: 4} is a sample object to send for the "single element case", the array case would be something like [{id: 2, hello: 3}, {id: 0, hello: 1}. So while the [*@to_pass] method works for arrays, it doesn't work for single objects